# Is using partial update on a document nested field going to ruin my bank account?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, datamodel

I have an application that uses this data model:

```json
objects: {
  0: { name: 'foo', items: [...] },
  1: { name: 'bar', items: [...] },
  ...
  999: { name: 'z', items: [...] }
}
```

At first I didn't think it could grow fast and now some documents have hundreds of entries and I'm forced to switch my account to Blaze plan.

I'm trying to see if there is a better approach to this model.
Currently I'm using this kind of logic to modify some entries "without modifying the whole structure":

```js
await setDoc(
  doc(getFirestore(), `/user/${user.uid}`),
  {
    objects[id]: {
      items: arrayUnion(...) // or arrayRemove
    }
  },
  { merge: true }
)

// Or when I want to remove an object

await setDoc(
  doc(getFirestore(), `/user/${user.uid}`),
  {
    objects[id]: deleteField()
  },
  { merge: true }
)

// Etc...
```

Let say `objects` is huge (thousands of entries), is `arrayUnion` (or `arrayRemove`) elaborated enough to avoid updating the whole field. My understanding of Google Cloud back-end is very limited and by "updating the whole field" I mean does the data internal reference gets rewritten (similar to `this.objects = {...}` in JS) and will it have any implications on the billing or will it be the same no matter the number of properties in `objects`?

If the answer is yes, could switching this structure to a document per object architecture potentially reduce the billing when the number of entries grows?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you are worried about the size of the document, you can always check against the maximum 1 MiB quota using the [Firestore Document Size Extension](https://extensions.dev/extensions/alexmamo/firestore-document-size).

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for sharing that with me, It'll come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore bills on document reads, document writes, outgoing bandwidth, and storage used. For more on this, see the documentation on [understanding Cloud Firestore billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing), and this [pricing example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example).

There is no charge on the incoming bandwidth, so the size of a write operation has no impact on the cost of that operation. Of course the size of the resulting documents *does* contribute to your storage cost.

The common alternative to consider is if it wouldn't be better to store each of these objects in a document of their own. If price is your differentiating factor, keep the [price calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing#blaze-calculator) handy to determine the impact of such a change.